# having trouble getting a formula to work with times

Tags: excel, if-statement

ok im trying to create a way of keeping all the hours i work in a excel spread sheet so i can work out what i should get paid.to what i actually get.

the trouble is anything over 39hours is paid at 1.5 normal pay. i thaught this mite solve / be my answer but seems to fail me somewhere i was hoping that a more experianced person could solve or guide me to solving my issue.

=IF(H20<39, (H20-39)*1.5*6.5, (H20*6.5))

using that i do get a number but its always minus.

if its not possible to do it this way and get the desired result or am i going about it all wrong??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. It uses `MAX` and `MIN` instead of `IF` to determine the results. I also don't think your formula is properly handling the 1.5 pay. I assumed that your pay rate is 6.5.

```
=((MAX(H20-39,0)*1.5)+MIN(H20,39))*6.5
```

Comment: yes worked great thanks makes it a lot easier now for the rest :) much kudos

Answer (score 0):

Here is `IF` solution:

```
=IF(H20<39,H20*6.5,39*6.5+(H20-39)*6.5*1.5)
```